# running a sql query with array elements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

what I am trying to do is extract elements of an array and running an sql query with the array element as the condition. The problem what I am facing is that the query does not return anything. The code is given below

```
//extracting the array elements
      foreach ($t as $value) {
      extract($value);

     }
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily_log where employee_log_id='$employee_log_id' AND log_date='$value'</br>";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row['in_time'];
        echo $row['out_time'];
```

The echo $row['in_time']  and echo $row['out_time']; does not show anything.

Can anybody help me to figure out what the problem is
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your sql query code is outside the `foreach` loop. The `$value` variable doesn't exist in that scope.
Try this:

```
foreach ($t as $value) {
    extract($value);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily_log where employee_log_id='$employee_log_id' AND log_date='$value'</br>";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['in_time'];
    echo $row['out_time'];
}
```

**EDIT:**
But I can't  understand what you are trying to do. I think you either need the `extract()` function or the `foreach` loop. Also, why is there a `</br>` html tag in your sql query string?
Do you want something like this?

```
foreach ($t as $key -> $value) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM daily_log where employee_log_id='$key' AND log_date='$value'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['in_time'];
    echo $row['out_time'];
}
```